# Expressing elements of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ as sums of squares

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, contest-math

Let $n\ge 2$ an integer. Find the lowest integer $\kappa(n)$ such that every elements in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ can be written as a sum of $\kappa(n)$ squares.

This statement can be found in the "smf 2017", a french contest. I was just wondering if it is a well-known result or are there references about it.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Lagrange's four-square theorem suggests $\kappa(n) \leq 4$. Are nonzero squares required? Have you tried calculating $\kappa(n)$ for a few small $n$ and looking that up in the OEIS?

Comment: May help:  For $n=p$ a prime, $\kappa(p)=2$.  (for fixed residue $m$, the sets of residues $x^2$ and $m-y^2$ each have $\frac {p+1}2$ elements hence must overlap).

Comment: Could you please add a link to this contest? Thanks!

Comment: The answer is surprisingly not elegant. There are different cases according to whether : $8$ divides $n$, primes dividing $n$ that are $=3$ mod $4$ appear once or more in the decomposition of $n$, etc. If you want I can provide a full solution, but I think that's not what you want. If I understand correctly the rules of this contest, the questions aren't in the literature, and there should be no references to it besides the contest itself

Comment: @MatthewConroy http://smf.emath.fr/files/smf_junior_sujets.pdf problem 9

Comment: @Max This is a theorem of Gauss, and it has appeared in the literature.  Just reading the comments now.  If I should delete my answer as this is a contest, let me know.

Comment: @Max it was just a curiosity, we see in class the case of two squares, four squares and for three squares it was more complicated.

Comment: @JavaMan : oh my bad, I guess the rules weren't applied then. You don't have to delete your answer, the contest is over now

Answer (score 4):

In Charles Small's 1977 paper ["Solutions of Waring's Problem $\bmod m$"](http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2319964.pdf?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), Small called the following "Essentially a Theorem of Gauss":

$$
\kappa(n) \leq \left\{ 
\begin{array}{ccl}
1 & &n=2
\\
2 & & p^2 \mid n \implies p \equiv 1 \pmod 4
\\
3 & & 8 \nmid n
\\
4 & & \text{ all } n
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your contribution but I cannot read the paper, I must buy it :D

Comment: The last condition should be "all other $n$", yes?

Comment: @MatthewConroy Yes it should be.  Thanks!

Comment: The last condition could be expressed as $8 | n$, since the implication in the third condition is that the second one is not satisfied.

Comment: @MatthewConroy I've edited it to what I originally intended

Answer (score 0):

The statement is a straightforward consequence of [Kneser's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kneser%27s_theorem_(combinatorics)).
Since
$$\mathbb{Z}/(n\mathbb{Z})\simeq\mathbb{Z}/(2^{\alpha_0}\mathbb{Z})\times \mathbb{Z}/(p_1^{\alpha_1}\mathbb{Z}) \times \ldots \times \mathbb{Z}/(p_m^{\alpha_m}\mathbb{Z})$$
by the Chinese remainder theorem, the set $Q$ of quadratic residues in $\mathbb{Z}/(n\mathbb{Z})$ fulfills
$$\left|Q\right| \geq \prod_{k=1}^{m}\frac{p_m^{\alpha_m}+1}{2} $$
and $\underbrace{Q+Q+\ldots+Q}_{\kappa(n)\text{ times}}\supseteq \mathbb{Z}/(n\mathbb{Z})$ for some $\kappa(n)\leq 2^{m+\alpha_0}$.

Comment: I don't follow this answer.  Of course CRT and the bound on $|Q|$ is fine, but the bound $\kappa(n) < 2^{m+a_0}$ is quite suboptimal if $m+a_0 \geq 2$.  Is there a deep connection I am missing here?  For example, does this give an upper bound on the problem for cubes?

Comment: @JavaMan: I never said it was an optimal bound: it is very far from being optimal, indeed. I just wanted to show a straightforward technique for proving the claim.